# Meteor/Handlebars jQuery Updating DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, meteor

Using *jQuery* and *Meteor* I am trying to bind the [TokenInput](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/) plugin to the DOM like so:

```
$(function(){
     console.log("binding tokeninput");
     $(".nameInput").tokenInput(friendsList.data)
});
```

The issue is that the particular DOM element is being redrawn (removed from the DOM and then re-added in a quick flash) occasionally. **I need to ensure that the plugin is ALWAYS in effect on that input.**

A few things come to mind:

- Could I use a callback from Meteor to re-apply it whenever it updates? I haven't found a callback from Meteor for when a template object is refreshed.
- Can I use some sort of reactive bind (like .on, though .on is only for events)?
- Am I doing this completely wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're DOM element being removed by something reactive. If `mytiem` changes its going to fire the '[rendered](http://docs.meteor.com/#template_rendered)' template callback

e.g

```
<template name="MeteorIsAwesome">
    {{#each myitem}}
        <div class="dom element meteor">

        </div>
    {{/each}}

    {{!comment - you can put it here or above}}
    <input class="nameInput" type="text">
</template>
```

Js (kind of the callback you might be looking for)

```
Template.MeteorIsAwesome.rendered = function () {
    $(".nameInput").tokenInput(friendsList.data)
}
```

One thing only worries me is if it ignores the state of the tokenbox when redrawing so it might become double tokenized

Comment: Actually I came to this conclusion a while ago and thought I'd let someone else answer it :) thanks for the confirmation